# Loading content before UI shows up (using AsyncTask and ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I'm trying to figure out how can I download content from server before running UI and setting ViewPager adapter. I got JSON file on my server and app reads that properly, but I can't update ViewPager.

Ideally, what I want to do is to make a dialog that says something like "Please wait, we are checking if there are any new contents" with circular loading thing (just to show that it's working) and if yes - to download it and make content fresh and if not to use last content.

It looks like that right now. It works as is - where should I take it from here?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp;
ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;
//int[] sounds;
int[] g;
String[] title;
int[] description;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);

    // Generate data

    title = new String[] { "A1", "A2", "A3","A4" };

    description = new int[] { R.string.a1, R.string.a2, R.string.a3, R.string.a4 };

    gun = new int[] {R.drawable.obr4,R.drawable.obr4,R.drawable.obr4,R.drawable.obr4};

    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, g, title,
            description);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
    }



    new GetUpdate().execute();
}

class GetUpdate extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    JSONObject jobj = null;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {             

        //JSON
        JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject data = jparser.getJSONFromUrl("http://myserver.com/file.json");                      

        String title2 = "";

        try {
            jobj = data.getJSONObject("party2");                
            title2 = jobj.getString("title");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //title = new String[] { title2,title2,title2,title2}; <- commented 'cause doesn't work

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting new `JSON` , just update the source list of the adapter and do 'notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter object like below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp;
ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;
//int[] sounds;
int[] g;
String[] title;
int[] description;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);

    // Generate data

    title = new String[] { "A1", "A2", "A3","A4" };

    description = new int[] { R.string.a1, R.string.a2, R.string.a3, R.string.a4 };

    gun = new int[] {R.drawable.obr4,R.drawable.obr4,R.drawable.obr4,R.drawable.obr4};

    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, g, title,
            description);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
    }



    new GetUpdate().execute();
}

class GetUpdate extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    JSONObject jobj = null;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {             

        //JSON
        JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject data = jparser.getJSONFromUrl("http://myserver.com/file.json");                      

        String title2 = "";

        try {
            jobj = data.getJSONObject("party2");                
            title2 = jobj.getString("title");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Change titles to ArrayList for better usage.
        title[4] = title2;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Won't title[4] just change title of the 4th element in the array?

Comment: You have Array object with just 4 items initialized. So you can't add a new element in this array. Ideally, you should use ArrayList with which you can add as `titles.add(title2)`.

Comment: Okay, I'm just changing to ArrayList. As far as I see, I can't initialize and add items in one line. I have to add one by one with .add method. Am I right?

Comment: If you have a String[] array with all the items you need. You can use `Arrays.asList(YOUR_STRING_ARRAY)`

Comment: And if I answered your original question, feel free to accept it as an answer :)

Comment: It helped, but I moved to making splash screen so I can manage update more easily :) notifyDataSetChanged() might be helpful in near future, nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

you can override onPostExecute() method of the AsyncTask to put your updating logic there